# AlgoExpert Question, Tournament Winner, Not passing all test cases

Tags: java, algorithm, hashtable, tournament

Tournament Winner: There's an algorithms tournament taking place in which teams of programmers compete against each other to solve algorithmic problems as fast as possible. Teams compete in a round robin, where each team faces off against all other teams. Only two teams compete against each other at a time. (Rest of problem in screenshot attached).

[image]

My code is only passing 6/10 test cases. I know my "bestTeam" is not getting updated but I'm not sure why. Please help me figure out where I am going wrong.

Test Case Failed:

Input:

```
{
  "competitions": [
    ["HTML", "C#"],
    ["C#", "Python"],
    ["Python", "HTML"]
  ],
  "results": [0, 0, 1]
}
```

My result was "C#" when it should be "Python"

```
class Program {

  public String tournamentWinner(
      ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> competitions, ArrayList<Integer> results) {
    
        Hashtable<String, Integer> tableTeamNameAndPoints = new Hashtable<>();
        String bestTeam = "";

        tableTeamNameAndPoints.put(bestTeam, 0);

        for(int i = 0; i < competitions.size(); i++){
          String winningTeamName = results.get(i) == 0 ? 
            competitions.get(i).get(1) : competitions.get(i).get(0);

          if(!tableTeamNameAndPoints.contains(winningTeamName)){
            tableTeamNameAndPoints.put(winningTeamName, 3);          
        }
          if(tableTeamNameAndPoints.contains(winningTeamName)){
            Integer updatedScore = tableTeamNameAndPoints.get(winningTeamName) + 3;
            tableTeamNameAndPoints.put(winningTeamName, updatedScore);          
          }

        if (tableTeamNameAndPoints.get(winningTeamName) > tableTeamNameAndPoints.get(bestTeam)){
            bestTeam = winningTeamName;
          }
      }
        
        return bestTeam;
  }
}
```

Comment: My best advice would be to step through this with your debugger, and find out exactly where its behaviour deviates from what you expect.

Comment: Thank you! @DawoodibnKareem This was in a AlgoExpert code editor problem so that wasn't an option, but you're right, next time I face this issue I will insert into my IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`containsKey`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#containsKey-java.lang.Object-) on your Hashtable instead of [`contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#contains-java.lang.Object-) on this line:

```java
if (!tableTeamNameAndPoints.contains(winningTeamName)) {
```

When you use [`contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#contains-java.lang.Object-), you're checking if the Hashtable contains a key that maps to the value provided. It's equivalent to the [`containsValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#containsValue-java.lang.Object-) method.

You can also remove the second `if` statement which is not needed (the condition is always `true`) and has the same `contains` problem:

```java
if (tableTeamNameAndPoints.contains(winningTeamName)) {
```